# Windows Phone 8 / Cordova / jQuery .find()

Tags: jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8

Has anyone had problems with Corodova 2.5.0 and jQuery 1.8.x / 1.9.1 when using jQuery.find() ? It seems that find() returns empty objects.

This was my starting point:

html

```
...

<ul id="here">
</ul>
```

javascript

```
 ..

$('#here').append('<li data-test="test1">first</li>');
$('#here').append('<li data-test="test2">second</li>');
$('#here').append('<li data-test="test3">third</li>');

var lis = $('#here').find('li');
console.log(lis);
$.each(lis, function (ind, rec) {
    console.log(rec);
});
```

console displays:

```
log: {}
log: {}
log: {}
```

Same code is fully functional in desktop browsers - without cordova :)

Comment: Is it fully functional in windows phone 8 without Cordova as well?

Comment: Seems to work in desktop IE10 and IE10 browser in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE10 on WP8 is unable to print the contents of the "rec" object even though the "li" elements are actually being added. I tried on a Cordova (v2.4.0) windows phone 8 app with jQuery (v1.7.1) and it seems to work ok with the below code

```
$.each(lis, function (ind, rec) {
    console.log(rec.innerHTML.toString());
});
```

Output is as below:

```
ScriptNotify :: first
ScriptNotify :: second
ScriptNotify :: third
```

Doing outerHTML instead prints:

```
ScriptNotify :: <li data-test="test1">first</li>
ScriptNotify :: <li data-test="test2">second</li>
ScriptNotify :: <li data-test="test3">third</li>
```

Full code from index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <ul id="here">
            </ul>
        </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
      <script>
        window.console = {
        log: function (str) { window.external.Notify(str); }
        };

        $('#here').append('<li data-test="test1">first</li>');
        $('#here').append('<li data-test="test2">second</li>');
        $('#here').append('<li data-test="test3">third</li>');

        var lis = $('#here').find('li');
        console.log(lis.length.toString());
        $.each(lis, function (ind, rec) {
        console.log(rec.outerHTML.toString());
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll downgrade to Cordova 2.4.0 and jQuery 1.7.1 as I coudn't get your code work in 2.5.0 & 1.8.1

Comment: Did change to cordova 2.4.0 & jQuery 1.7 and does not work - are testing with emulator or device ?

Comment: Tested on both. I've updated the answer above to include the full code from the index.html. Hope it works.